# Java fastest way to get cardinality of BitSet intersection

Tags: java, intersection, bitset, cardinality

The function below takes two `BitSets`, makes a copy of the first (it must not be overridden), intersects the copy with the second (bitwise AND) and returns the cardinality of the result.

```
public int getIntersectionSize(BitSet bits1, BitSet bits2) {
    BitSet copy = (BitSet) bits1.clone();
    copy.and(bits2);
    return copy.cardinality();
}
```

I'm interested if this code can be sped up? This function is called billion of times so even a microsecond speed up makes sense plus I'm curious about the fastest possible code.

Comment: One idea: you could try to avoid creating a new BitSet that you're just throwing away.

Comment: More information required: how long does it take to call a billion times? And can you change your algorithm to not call it a billion times?

Comment: I didn't check the BitSet internals but it might be possible to do it all in one go, instead of doing an `and` and then `cardinality` try to count the cardinality **while** doing the `and` manually?

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk it looks like the `intersects` method could be adapted to do this, by replacing the `(a & b) != 0` with `Long.countBits(a & b)` and summing. **But** this would require access to `words`, which is private.

Comment: Conventional wisdom suggests that, rather than the fastest way, you should develop a correct way that reads will and is maintainable.  Execution speed optimization is something you delve into once you've proved that your solution is a performance bottleneck by benchmarking (most of the time, it isn't).

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to use each `BitSet` several times, it could be worthwhile to create a `long` array corresponding to each `BitSet`. For each `BitSet`:

```
long[] longs = bitset.toLongArray();
```

Then you can use the following method, which avoids the overhead of creating a cloned `BitSet`. (This assumes that both arrays are the same length).

```
int getIntersectionSize(long[] bits1, long[] bits2) {
    int nBits = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<bits1.length; i++)
        nBits += Long.bitCount(bits1[i] & bits2[i]);
    return nBits;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative version, but I'm not sure if it is really faster, depends on `nextSetBit`.

```
public int getIntersectionsSize(BitSet bits1, BitSet bits2) {
   int count = 0;
   int i = bits1.nextSetBit(0);
   int j = bits2.nextSetBit(0);
   while (i >= 0 && j >= 0) {
      if (i < j) {
         i = bits1.nextSetBit(i + 1);
      } else if (i > j) {
         j = bits2.nextSetBit(j + 1);
      } else {
         count++;
         i = bits1.nextSetBit(i + 1);
         j = bits2.nextSetBit(j + 1);
      }
   }
   return count;
}
```

The above is the readable version, hopefully good enough for the compiler, but you could optimize it manually I guess:

```
public int getIntersectionsSize(BitSet bits1, BitSet bits2) {
   int count = 0;
   for (int i = bits1.nextSetBit(0), j = bits2.nextSetBit(0); i >= 0 && j >= 0; ) {
      while (i < j) {
         i = bits1.nextSetBit(i + 1);
         if (i < 0)
            return count;
      }
      if (i == j) {
         count++;
         i = bits1.nextSetBit(i + 1);
      }
      while (j < i) {
         j = bits2.nextSetBit(j + 1);
         if (j < 0)
            return count;
      }
      if (i == j) {
         count++;
         j = bits2.nextSetBit(j + 1);
      }
   }
   return count;
}
```

Comment: @BrandonMcHomery If you want to use BitSet functionality I think your version is probably the best you can get. The above could be good for "sparse" BitSets. I can delete it if you want to.

Comment: @maraca this will be slower because you are going bit by bit, internally `BitSet` works per word so the number of operations for let's say `and` is much smaller.

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk yes, could still be better for "sparse" BitSets (most bits are false) or not?

Comment: @maraca for extremely sparse sets most probably yes

Comment: @BrandonMcHomery you could try to implement Andy Turner's idea, but because you would need to call toLongArray on both bitSets you clone them both, so I guess that's not faster either.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for a solution to this recently and here's what I came up with:

```
int intersectionCardinality(final BitSet lhs, final BitSet rhs) {
    int lhsNext;
    int retVal = 0;
    int rhsNext = 0;

    while ((lhsNext = lhs.nextSetBit(rhsNext)) != -1 &&
            (rhsNext = rhs.nextSetBit(lhsNext)) != -1) {
        if (rhsNext == lhsNext) {
            retVal++;
            rhsNext++;
        }
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

Perhaps someone would like to take the time to compare the different solutions here and post the results...